# Reading file from GDrive (on Google App Engine) httperror 500

Tags: google-app-engine, google-data-api, http-error, server-error

Trying to read file from GDrive (api v2) on (Google App Engine) and getting error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-anao2UgM returned "">
```

Yesterday (2014-01-22) all worked fine but today getting error. Anyone had same issue?

Answer (score 0):

check for mixed message content  error i.e. that is when you send the data from secured site to non-secured site means data passing from https to http site although very few browser  have that capability .

Do reply if it helps you